# Remove alt tags from Calendar

Tags: jquery, calendar

Has anyone been able to successfully remove the alt tags/(hover text) from events in the sharepoint 2010 calendar. I am trying to use Jquery to strip them out, but am having no success.

I have even tried the following to remove all alt tags:

`$(document).ready(
    function(){
       $('a').removeAttr("alt");    });`

Any help will huge.  I am presenting the calendar to the execs tomorrow afternoon and need a quick fix.

cheers

Comment: Note I've also tried ms-acal-default-hover in the above code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first issue is that the hover text is not in the alt attribute of the a tag. I think it is actually in the title attribute of a div tag.

But there's a bigger issue. The SP 2010 calendar is rendered asynchronously. When you use $(document).ready, your script runs too early, before the calendar is rendered on the page. Even if you delay your script, it won't work if your users navigate to other months.

A workaround I have used is to run the script at regular intervals, every 100 or 200 ms. See an example here:
http://blog.pathtosharepoint.com/2010/06/16/html-calculated-column-solutions-for-sp-2010-part-iv/

Comment: Christophe, pleasure to meet you.  It was your solution I used.  I found in a comment a fix you recommended: November 9, 2010 at 3:01 am
Christophe

Shane, I found the time to look at the rollover issue, and here is how I fixed it:
- in the script, look for this line:
NodeSet[i].innerHTML = CellContent;
-replace it with:
NodeSet[i].innerHTML = CellContent;
NodeSet[i].parentNode.parentNode.title=NodeSet[i].innerText || NodeSet[i].textContent;

Answer (score 0):

Anchor tag uses title attribute to show a tooltip try to remove it, here is your code

> $(document).ready( function(){ $('a').removeAttr("title"); });